# Error accessing files through Samba, cifs-utils and smbclient

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I have strange errors trying to access files shared in our corporate Windows network. It started yesterday. First, I wasn't able to copy shared ISO image to my local directory: download stopped at first 91.5 MB (file size is ~3GB). Also, the copying window froze. Lesser files were read without problem.

I reinstalled `cifs-utils` and mounted share manually (I used `autofs` before):

```
sudo mount.cifs -o credentials=/root/.credentials //server/share /mnt
```

But I got the same behaviour of copy window and `cp`. So I reinstalled `samba-common` purging configuration files. It fixed problem with sharing my files, but did not fix the mentioned problem.

Now, when I try to copy another large file, it doesn't start at all and freezes again. OK, let's try `smbclient`:

```
$ sudo smbclient -A /root/.credentials //infomrk/install
Domain=[ZAOMRK] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.23]
smb: \>
...
smb: \Programmers\Language\Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2\> get delphicbuilder_xe2_4316_win_dl.iso /home/karimov-danil/Install/delphicbuilder_xe2_4316_win_dl.iso 

parallel_read returned NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
```

My `/var/log/samba/log.winbindd`:

```
$ tail -20 /var/log/samba/log.winbindd 
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.320867,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1204(winbindd_register_handlers)
  unable to initialize domain list
[2014/05/23 12:06:42,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1453(main)
  winbindd version 4.1.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2013
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.389438,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3196(initialize_winbindd_cache)
  initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.391433,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_util.c:634(init_domain_list)
  Could not fetch our SID - did we join?
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.391535,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1204(winbindd_register_handlers)
  unable to initialize domain list
[2014/05/23 12:06:42,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1453(main)
  winbindd version 4.1.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2013
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.457973,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3196(initialize_winbindd_cache)
  initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.804879,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_util.c:634(init_domain_list)
  Could not fetch our SID - did we join?
[2014/05/23 12:06:42.805072,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1204(winbindd_register_handlers)
  unable to initialize domain list
```

Can somebody point me out what should I do now and how do I quick resolve this problem?

UPD: Somehow I found that switching to internal network adapter (NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)) resolves problem but I'd like to use default one (3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado] (rev 74)).

Comment: You can close this question. It was the hardware problem. Replacing card solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the MTU settings of both systems? If the MTU is too high, your connection could hang when transferring large files.

Comment: This is actually comment, not an answer... MTU is set to automatic.

Comment: It's actually an answer, not a comment. Don't use automatic for MTU. Set a value that works best for the NIC. The default MTU is usually 1500, so try 1000 or lower.As I said before, coming from experience, MTU errors causes this kind of issue.